# If I don't destroy the posix's semaphore, can it be detroyed when the process exits?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, posix, semaphore

I used posix unnamed semaphore on `ubuntu` with `C`, but I haven't destroyed it by calling `sem_destroy()`. My question is whether the semaphore would be destroyed when the process exits. If it can't, how can I know where the semaphore is and whether there is a `command` can destroy it as `ipcrm` at `system v's semaphore`?